# Is there any situation that fifo faster than sjf

Tags: cpu

In cpu scheduling, is there any possible situation that first in first out can faster than shortest job first(non-preemptive)

Answer (score 0):

Faster doesn't always make sense here.
If you sum up the time for a bunch of jobs they will equal the same thing at the end ([single thread] or [single core ignoring context switching overhead]).

For multiple threads and/or processes FIFO's are faster when the jobs are very small as there is less overhead involved in queuing and dequeuing. When the algorithm dominates the CPU time FIFO is probably faster.

For overhead reasons FIFO's also perform better when you can add items to the queue in what would be statically similar to SJF. Meaning that you can approximate what the SJF would be by the order which you add things to the queue.

NOTE: I don't have sources for this, it simply makes logical sense.